# How to compile apv library in windows to read pdf file in android

Tags: android, pdf-reader

I want to add a pdf viewing feature in my android app.
I got results that apv library is best & fast.

Can anyone tell how to compile that stuffs in windows.

Suggestion are welcomed fro other pdf viewing libraries also.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Nothing,just moved to pdf viewer available to me from market & used that in my code.

Comment: I used abode reader in my code

Comment: Hi @Greenhorn, successfully complied the apv library in eclipse project to read pdf.

Comment: Hey Shashank pls tell how you have compiled the apv library I am also looking for that.